# Origin of these images of the Enterprise in space-dock?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-enterprise, uss-enterprise

[image: Image 1 of Enterprise in Space spacedock (side-on view)]
[image: Image 2 of Enterprise in Space spacedock (rear view)]

In *Star Trek Chronology*, the above two images are featured. I was just wondering what their source is as I don't recall seeing the *Enterprise* in spacedock during the series or movies.

Comment: That looks like it's from *Star Trek: The Movie*, but it's been a while since I watched it

Comment: @JasonBaker: do you mean *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* (the one with V'Ger in it), because in that movie the Enterprise had undergone a refit to have the rectangular warp nacelles which these images don't have.  That movie is the only time I ever recall seeing the *Enterprise* in spacedock too, but that's not it I'm afraid!

Comment: @JasonBaker : Do you mean *The Motion Picture*?  I'm just clarifying because the image above shows the Enterprise as it appeared in *The Original Series*, but *The Motion Picture* only has the refit Enterprise, which looks quite different from above.

Comment: @N.Soong : Were you scanning my brainwaves?!

Comment: Yeah, I meant *The Motion Picture*; like I said, been a while (cc. @Praxis)

Comment: @Praxis - my synaptic scanner comes in handy sometimes ;)

Comment: @N.Soong : I wonder if it was art created just for the book?  Do you own it?  It may have an image credit.

Comment: @Praxis the thought had occurred to me too.  I suspect though that it may have been a promotional shot or something made that was supposed to be used in the series sometime but just never got used.

Comment: @Praxis - I've checked the book and can't see any image credits - there are a lot of images though

Comment: There's also [this similar image](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/File:Enterprise_Pike_spacedock.jpg) that seems to have been created for [Ships of the Line 2005](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Ships_of_the_Line_2005).

Comment: @Hypnosifl that image is similar granted, but the images I'm asking about aren't computer generated by the look of it; I'd say they are actual models

Comment: The book is from 1993 I believe, which is a little bit before the time when they started using CGI rendering to draw ships in the *Star Trek* universe.  I'm going with it being an actual model, but I doubt the spacedock part was built in the 60s during the time of *TOS*.  I suspect it is a model of the original Enterprise placed within the drydock frame used in *The Motion Picture* and *Wrath of Khan*, and photographed either as a promotion some time after those films or expressly for the book.

Comment: A similar image is used on the [2006 Star Trek calendar](https://simg2.imagesbn.com/p/9780740752933_p0_v1_s600.jpg) - series Enterprise in the spacedock model that was used in TMP.

Comment: And [this](http://www.ncc1701.us/18.html) is a blog by a fan who acquired the *The Motion Picure* stardock model at an auction (apparently in 2008). He says the model was modified and used in Generations.

Comment: Even if 1993 was before they were using CGI rendering to create animated models on the show itself, that doesn't necessarily imply the image isn't CGI, since it's a lot less costly and time-intensive to render a single still image (shown at fairly small size in a book, so resolution needn't be so high) than an animated sequence involving many frames. That said, since they had models for both the original Enterprise and the TMP spacedock it's quite possible they used them to create those pictures.

Comment: Wow, can't find this image anywhere else except some fan site where it was clear they stole the image from the book. My best guess was it was something created for Star Trek Phase II, before that was cancelled in favor of the Motion Picture. They did get a bit of pre-production done on that series, including some special effects, models and sets before it got canned.

Comment: @BBlake: No, that doesn't match with the history of the spacedock model as outlined [here](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_spacedocks#USS_Enterprise_spacedock_info). Also, the [Phase II Enterprise](https://www.google.com/search?q=Phase+II+Enterprise) model already had the blocky nacelles. I agree with Praxis and Hypnosifi's assessment; a mismatched combination of the models, made after TMP, potentially specifically for the 1993 book.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense

Comment: Those spacedock pictures call to mind an episode of ST:Enterprise "In a Mirror, Darkly". It's been a while since I saw the episode, but the way I remember it, I thought the "future" NCC-1701 was in a space dock at some point in that episode.

Comment: @AnthonyX I'd be really interested to see those.  I doubt, however, that they would be the source, b/c that book was written before *ENT*, nevertheless it's still interesting!

Comment: @AnthonyX : *ENT* is from the 2000s and used CGI ships, while the book above is from 1993 and has photos of models.  See my answer below.  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much searching, it seems that the key to understanding the images in the original post is the following concept art:

[image]

The notion of an "orbital drydock" for repairing and refitting starships was first developed for *Star Trek: Phase II* (a television continuation of *The Original Series* that was aborted in favour of *The Motion Picture*, with various ideas from the project also being channelled into the film).

The above sketch, made by artist Mike Minor around 1977 while *Phase II* was being developed, is the original idea for the drydock.

It clearly shows the original USS Enterprise (no refit) in the drydock structure.

When *Phase II* was abandoned and *The Motion Picture* was announced, Minor's design was dropped in favour of one by Andrew Probert.  The following sketch by Probert (1978) shows an Enterprise that is very close in appearance to the refit one, sitting in the drydock:

[image]

What is *really* important to note is that, according to [this detailed site](http://ottens.co.uk/forgottentrek/designing-the-motion-picture-drydock/) (where I found the above sketches), the first working model of the drydock was built in **1977**, two years before *The Motion Picture* came out.

The 1977 model of the drydock was based expressly on Mike Minor's design, not on Probert's, and was built by Magicam.   According to the site, this model "closely resembled the final product" that was seen two years later in *The Motion Picture*.

Given that the original Magicam drydock was based on Minor's design, which was intended for the original Enterprise, and given that Probert's refit Enterprise wasn't devised until at least a year later, we can conclude that a **model of the original Enterprise would have been placed into the 1977 Magicam drydock model** — indeed, there is no record of any other type of model of Enterprise existing at that time — thereby creating the most likely source of photos of a non-refitted Enterprise in drydock for *Star Trek Chronology*.

Comment: I believe this is what they showed in Star Trek Into Darkness? It's where they build the U.S.S. Vengeance.

Comment: "the original Magicam drydock was based on Minor's design (...) we can conclude that a model of the original Enterprise would have been placed into the 1977 Magicam drydock model" - wait, are you saying that the drydock in the photos shown in the question is supposed to be based on Minor's design? It looks much more similar to Probert's design, and actually, it looks like it could pretty much be *exactly the same* drydock design as what appeared in the finished film.

Answer (score -2):

**The photos you posted are from the space dock in the opening scene in the movie Star Trek II "The Wrath of Khan."** The photos are not from the same angle, but it's the same spacedock. You can tell that those photo's are from that particular space dock by the **unique windowing of that space dock** not seen elsewhere. Lt. Saviik is piloting the Enterprise out of that particular space dock. **At the 2:40 & 2:50 mark of the following video** you can clearly see the windows I'm talking about and match them up with the photo's you posted.

The photo on the left appears to have rectangular nacelles on my screen. Either way there are no instances of a docked Enterprise in the series or movies anywhere with round nacelles. But to answer the your first question at least partially, as I stated, that spacedock is from "The Wrath of Khan."

To answer the second part of your statement about not remembering when the Enterprise was in space dock.

Aside from **Star Trek The Motion Picture**, which you have already mentioned, there are other instances of the Enterprise being in space dock. For ST: "The Motion Picture" see 1:28 mark of following video:

The enterprise is clearly seen in space dock in the **third movie, "The Search for Spock."** At the beginning of the movie the crew steals the Enterprise and the Excelsior gives chase. The enterprise is seen in space dock several times and is seen leaving space dock. Just watching the scene puts a smile on my face, love it when Kirk ignores Starfleet. This is the infamous scene with the famous/infamous warp vs. transwarp drive (that sputters and kerplunks). Here is a Youtube link to that wondrous scene (Check the 4:23 mark if for some reason you don't want to watch the whole clip):

In the **sixth movie "The Undiscovered Country"** the Enterprise A is seen inside and then leaving space dock. Check out 1:06 of this Youtube clip:

Comment: Sorry, but they're not the same photos!  Yep, that's the same space dock by the looks of it, but you'll notice that the warp nacelles are the rectangular ones - this is the *Enterprise* refit, not the original *Constitution* with the cylindrical nacelles!

Comment: The photo on the left has the rectangular ones, right? Or is the scan just not clear? There are no instances of the cylindrical ones in space dock. I'll edit my answer to reflect.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps the scan isn't clear but both pictures show the cylindrical nacelles

Comment: I've tried adding the time indexes for the clips but it just isn't taking for some reason!  Anybody who can help out I'd be much obliged

Comment: @N_Soong Either way what I stated in my opening statement, which hasn't changed is that this photo is from the Space Dock in "The Wrath of Khan." There are no instances in TOS from the 60's of the Enterprise being in a space dock with the round nacelles. As for the second part of your question I gave the instances of the other times Kirk's Enterprises were in spacedock.

Comment: Okay, upvote for the effort ;)

Comment: @N_Soong When you find there is no other answer other then the one's I've provided, I'd appreciate you taking another look at my answer. Since the nacelles were changed before "The Motion Picture" was released, the only place that there'd be round nacelles would be in TOS. There are no instances of a space dock that I'm aware of in TOS. They do orbit a space station in "Trouble with Tribbles." There's nothing that looks like that particular space dock besides the one from "Wrath of Khan."

Comment: @N_Soong I've been reading up on this. The refit didn't happen until Star Trek IV. So in Wrath of Khan it still was not a full refit according to canon sources. However, what we are calling the "nacelles" are really the "nacelle pylons" and don't necessarily have to do with the refit as some have suggested above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24900/discussion-between-n-soong-and-jmfb).

Comment: @JMFB: The chatroom is closed meanwhile ("frozen for inactivity", it says), therefore here: "The refit didn't happen until Star Trek IV" - that is incorrect. The refit of the original ship happened at the beginning (or rather, right before) Star Trek I. Star Trek IV introduces a *new* ship (after the original one had been destroyed in Star Trek III), which happens to have the same exterior design as the previous one after its refit from Star Trek I. Two of the most prominent changes from the refit are the angled nacelle pylons and the rectangular nacelles.